# XMPPFRAMEWORK - how to get message body from Xmppmessage when use xmppMessageArchiveManagement

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I'm getting XmppMessage from the mam delegate method

```
- (void)xmppMessageArchiveManagement:(XMPPMessageArchiveManagement *)xmppMessageArchiveManagement didReceiveMAMMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{
   NSLog(@"message ---->>> %@",message);
}
```

the console log printing like below..

```
<message id='aeb213' to='juliet@capulet.lit/chamber'>
  <result xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:2' queryid='f27' id='28482-98726-73623'>
    <forwarded xmlns='urn:xmpp:forward:0'>
      <delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' stamp='2010-07-10T23:08:25Z'/>
      <message xmlns='jabber:client' from="witch@shakespeare.lit" to="macbeth@shakespeare.lit">
        <body>Hail to thee</body>
      </message>
    </forwarded>
  </result>
</message>
```

How to get the body from the above message ?

Comment: Hi!! have any solution?? regards!

Comment: Hi @Dverdugo , the solution is.. NSString *msg = [[[[[message elementForName:@"result"] elementForName:@"forwarded"] elementForName:@"message"] elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];